# android firebase database java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

Please help here (fore job interview)

I'm trying to upload an image , when it's starts uploding , it crashes 
and removes the two basic childrens (image,thumb image)

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.pc.newchatj, PID: 9350
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.pc.newchatj.SettingsActivity$1.onDataChange(SettingsActivity.java:103)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:75)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:63)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

And in my Firebase database it removes the two childrens (image , thumb_image)

anyone please help

```
mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
            String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
            String thumb_image = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();

            mName.setText(name);
            mStatus.setText(status);

            if (!image.equals("default")) {
                Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(mDisplayImage);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I've added StorageReference for both (image , thumb image)

```
filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){

                    UploadTask uploadTask = thumb_filepath.putBytes(thumb_byte);
                    uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> thumb_task) {

                            if (thumb_task.isSuccessful()){

                                //getting regular image download url
                                filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                                        download_urll = uri.toString();

                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Regular fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });


                                //getting thumbnail download url
                                thumb_filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Uri thumb_uri) {

                                        thumb_downloadUrl = thumb_uri.toString();

                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "thumb failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });


                                Map update_hashMap = new HashMap();
                                update_hashMap.put("image" , download_urll);
                                update_hashMap.put("thumb_image" , thumb_downloadUrl);


                                mUserDatabase.updateChildren(update_hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                            avi_settings.smoothToHide();
                                            avi_settings.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Successfully uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                        }

                                    }
                                });

                            }



                        }
                    });

                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error uploading file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    avi_settings.smoothToHide();
                    avi_settings.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you please indicate at which particular line of code does this error occur?

Comment: @AlexMamo it's in the line of the image 
String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

Comment: @AlexMamo i'm new to stackOverflow , can i post the hole code here ?

Comment: There is no need for the entire code. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to get the data from the `dataSnapshot` object, you should check if that data actually exist:

```
mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) { //Check for existens
            String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);
            String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue(String.class);
            String thumb_image = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue(String.class);

            mName.setText(name);
            mStatus.setText(status);

            if (!image.equals("default")) {
                Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(mDisplayImage);
            }   
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
});
```

Also is best to pass `String.class` to the `getValue()` method insted of casting it to String. You will **not** get any `NullPointerException` anymore.

Comment: So ? ... that dose not do anything , the data exists on the Storage !

Comment: You said you get `NullPointerException` at this line of code `String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();`. It doesn't matter if the data exist in the Storage, you should check if it exist in your `dataSnapshot` object. Is has nothing to do with what exist, or does not exist in the Firebase Storage. Have you even tried my solution above? Does it work?

Comment: yes i've tried it , i'm storing an image in the firebase storage , getting it's URL and storing it on the firebase database , but when i store it it crashes

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question or as a comment and indicate the line at which line of code it occurs.

Comment: Hi Johnny! Is there everything alright, have you solved the issue?

Comment: hi Alex , no i fixed the image issue , but thumb image still deleting , it's complicated, the first time i upload it deletes it , the second time it adds the field to the firebase

Comment: The fact that you get another error, it means that the initial error disappeared and this are good news :) but this sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question that cannot be answered in a comment or using only the data above. As a personal guess, I think that you are using a wrong database reference but in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote NullPointerException rises in line

```
String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
```

The error message says you try to invoke `.toString()` on an null object. 
You should save the result from `String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue()` and check if it's not null before calling `.toSring()` method.

Comment: Error appers inString image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

Comment: ok, sorry for this ;) .... but checking the value before calling the method could help nevertheless

Answer (score 0):

use it

```
store.setUrl((String) snapshot1.child("url").getValue());
store.setName((String) snapshot1.child("name").getValue());
```

Instead of

```
store.setUrl(snapshot1.child("url").getValue().toString());
store.setName(snapshot1.child("name").getValue().toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

**I know it's not something technical but it could be a mistake, so please check your child or reference name if it is same as on your database. I spent 3 days in fixing related bug and ending up with finding wrong reference name.
I hope if it can help.
Thanks.**

Comment: Please, don't post several times the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66714423/9193372).